# How to get rid of the POST details in the json message?

Tags: c++, json

I am receiving a msg contains JSON and I have a problem to parse into JSON details. The msg I receive is :

```
POST /api/school/2/order HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Guzzle/4.0 curl/7.21.4 PHP/5.5.7
content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 12

{
 "json msg is here"
}
```

I want to git rid of the first 4 lines ..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What you have is a complete [HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) message. You should handle it properly and read documentation about HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That is because you are retrieving the data as plain text.**
Then you would use libCURL to get the actual JSON data. Then parse it with some C++ library like jsoncpp.